# If the first derivative is the slope at a point and the first integral is the area under the curve, then what is the second derivative?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry

If the first derivative of the function $y(x)$,
$$\frac{dy}{dx}$$,
 is the slope at a point and the first indefinite integral
$$\int dx y(x)$$
 is the area under the curve, then what is the geometric meaning of the second derivative?

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$$

or the second indefinite integral ?

$$\int dx \int dx y$$

is there some geometric sense in which to understand/interpret the general differential or integral operator?

Comment: If I recall correctly, in one dimensional functions mapping a scalar to another scalar, the second derivative represents curvature.

Comment: The second derivative determines the [concavity](http://www.sosmath.com/calculus/diff/der15/der15.html) of a function.

Comment: Second derivative represents convexity and not curvature.

Comment: Convexity, curvature, pot-ey-to, po-tah-to. The distinction is subtle and not the point of the question. The point is that the second derivative measures how much the graph of a function differs from a straight line. The distinction between convexity and curvature is whether this difference is measured strictly vertically from line to graph, or actual closest distance. So apart from pathological examples they measure the same thing on different scales.